# javascript jquery dropdown listbox - How to set option text at specific index (not selected!)

Tags: javascript, jquery, html-select, dropdown

My question is, using javascript / jquery, **"How do you change the value of a dropdown option at a specific index that is NOT the selected index?"**

I have a dropdown list of values.  User can select an option.  I have a method which enables the user to change the value at that selected option.  The value gets changed and all is well.

**Here is my issue:**  If the user decides to cancel, or changes to a different value in the list without saving the changes to the database, I want to **undo** the value change.

- I have the index of the changed option.
- I have the old value of the changed option.
- I have the new value of the changed option.

If the user has selected a different option, I don't want to change the index of the newly selected option.  I just want to reset the value of the option the user changed.

**I've tried a .each method:**

```
var changedTitle = $('#ddTitle').text();

$("#ddTitle option").each(function() {
  if($(this).text() == changedTitle) {
    $(this).text(savedTitle);            
  }                        
});
```

I like the idea of looping through each one but I never see execution loop through a second time and the browser never comes back.

**I've tried a .filter method:**

```
var changedTitle = $('#ddTitle').text();

$("#ddTitle option").filter(function(index) { return $(this).text() === changedTitle; }).attr('selected', 'selected');

$("#ddTitle option").filter(function() {  
    return $(this).text() === changedTitle;
}).prop('selected', true);  // changes the selected option
```

**I got the above filter code to work but it sets the selected option.**

```
$("#ddTitle option").filter(function() {  
    return $(this).text() === changedTitle;
}).prop('text', savedTitle);  // execution never returns
```

**I tried using the text property on the option** but jquery gets very busy and execution never returns.

**I've tried finding by the text value**, which is silly because I know the index:

```
$("#ddTitle option[value='" + theText + "']").attr('selected', 'selected');
```

**If these get an option it is the first option (0) or the browser hangs.**

Is there a way to change the text value at a specified index programmatically in javascript or using jquery?  Nothing I've tried works.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To change the value of the 5th option, do:

```
$('#yourselect').children('option:eq(4)').html('your text');
```

Comment: I really do think you have me on the right track. I'm still trying.

Comment: It turns out the change made by the user does not effect the html.  In order to get more help, I need to take the answer check away.  If I can get something working with your suggestion, I'll give it back.  I'm sorry. :-(

Comment: this answers : How do you change the value of a dropdown option at a specific index that is NOT the selected index?

Comment: After much needed rest and additional thought, I think I can use a different event before the user selects a different option.  Thank you.